# issue in  a scrollView

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a UIScrollView in which I need to add two videos, but I'm facing the following issue:

*I have a scrollView with two pages.If I add only one the first video, it works ok.In the first page of the scrollView I'll have the video and the second one will be empty.

*If I try to add both videos-the first page of the scrollView it will be empty and the scond one will contain the second video.

No matter how I act I cannot have both videos in the scrollView.

Here is what I did:

```
 scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2" ofType:@"mp4"];

videoPlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1]];
videoPlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2]];

[[videoPlayer1 view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 335)];
[videoPlayer1 prepareToPlay];


[videoPlayer1 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
videoPlayer1.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self.scrollView addSubview:[videoPlayer1 view]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer1];

[[videoPlayer2 view] setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 335)];
[videoPlayer2 prepareToPlay];

[videoPlayer2 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
videoPlayer2.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self.scrollView addSubview:[videoPlayer2 view]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:
 MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:videoPlayer2];

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640, 400);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Please help.thank you